# Custom validator in Laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am upgrading my Laravel application from 4 to 5. However, I have a custom validator that I cannot get to work.

In L4, I made a *validators.php* file and included it in *global.php* using `require app_path().'/validators.php';`.

I tried doing somewhat the same in L5. I dropped a validator in *app/Validators/Validators.php*, and updated my *composer.json*.

```
"files": [
    "app/Validators/Validators.php"
]
```

However, now nothing renders on any page. What've I done wrong?

Comment: Check your logs - `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` and/or your webserver's log files.

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @ceejayoz It doesn't log anything when failing. 
lukasgeiter Yes I did

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Make a bind class where you can implement each rule you want extending `Validator` class.
2. Make a service provider that extends `ServiceProvider`.
3. Add your custom validator provider at `config/app.php` file.

You can create the bind at `Services` folder like this:

```
namespace MyApp\Services;

class Validator extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator{

    public function validateFoo($attribute, $value, $parameters){  
        return $value == "foo"
    }
}
```

Then, use a service provider to extends the core:

```
namespace MyApp\Providers;

use MyApp\Services\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

    public function boot()
    {
        \Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new Validator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

Finally, import your service provider at `config/app.php` like so:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    ...
    'MyApp\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider';
]
```

Comment: Good! Very glad to help you

Comment: WHY DOESN'T THE DOCUMENTATION COVER THIS?!! It literally has 3 paragraphs on the entire subject.

Comment: @manix I wish I had seen this earlier. I just posted a similar (but different) answer on this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817045#30971705 I had to show how to use other input though so I guess it was worth it.

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647044/how-to-specify-the-default-error-message-when-extending-the-validation-class-in) is how to make validation errors localization;

also you could replace error message parameters by adding method called like ```replaceYourCustomRuleName($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){}```

i think it will be helpful with this question;

Comment: Is there a way to register custom validators without using the Validator facade? I'd love to be able to access it in AppServiceProvider by accessing $this->app, but I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Just spend 2 days with this ****, while writing it in native PHP would take some seconds... Damn, Laravel!

Comment: @Lisa Too little too late, but you can use `app('validator')->resolver(...)` or `$this->app->validator->resolver(...)` in `AppServiceProvider@boot` method.

Answer (score 7):

so here's what I did on adding a custom validation. this is for laravel 5.1

1. run `PHP Artisan make:request MyFormValidationRequest` file is created under `app\Requests\MyFormValidationRequest.php`

Here's the initial code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class MyFormValidationRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            //

        ];
    }
}
```

---

**IMPORTANT**: Change the return value of `authorize()` method to true, if you're not doing any authentication. it's initial value is false. else you get a white page with a "Forbidden" error message.

---

2. I added a rule under the function `rules()`, here's what it looks like

   ```
   public function rules() {
       return [
           'activeuntil' => 'today_onwards'
       ];
   }
   ```

`today_onwards` is my new validation.

3. I created a folder named 'Services' under App folder
4. I created a file named 'ValidatorExtended.php' under App\Services folder , here's the code below:

   ```
    <?php 

        namespace App\Services;     
        use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
        use Carbon\Carbon;

        class ValidatorExtended extends Validator {

            private $_custom_messages = array(        
                "today_onwards" => "The :attribute must be today onwards",
            );

            public function __construct( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array() ) {
                parent::__construct( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes );

                $this->_set_custom_stuff();
            }

            protected function _set_custom_stuff() {
                //setup our custom error messages
                $this->setCustomMessages( $this->_custom_messages );
            }

            protected function validateTodayOnwards( $attribute, $value ) {     
                $now =  strtotime('-1 day');
                $valueDateFormat =  strtotime($value);

                if($valueDateFormat > $now){
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }        
           }
       }
   ```

**Note:** the validateTodayOnwards method is where you put your logic. 
the name of the method should always start in "validate" then the name of your new validation key which should be in title case,

**Another note** your validation key should be separated by underscore and all small letters, in this case, "today_onwards". the underscore should be put before all first capital letters in the method name. I hope I explained it good.

TodayOnwards method is equivalent to validation name of "today_onwards",

another example, if I created validateOldPassword, your validation key should be "old_password".

5. I added below code in `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` inside `boot()` method.

   ```
   Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array())
   {
       return new ValidatorExtended($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
   });
   ```
6. Don't forget to add below library, one is the Validator class and the other is your own class which is the "`ValidatorExtended`".

   ```
   use App\Services\ValidatorExtended;

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
   ```
7. Here's what the whole file looks like, [`app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`]

   ```
   <?php

       namespace App\Providers;

       use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
       use App\Services\ValidatorExtended;
       use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

       class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
       {
       /**
        * Bootstrap any application services.
        *
        * @return void
       */
            public function boot()
            {
                //
                Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array())
                {
                    return new ValidatorExtended($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
                });
            }

            /**
             * Register any application services.
             *
             * @return void
            */
            public function register()
            {
               //
           }
       }
   ```
8. That's it. done. you created your own custom validation.
9. Additionally, if you want to use it in your controller, below is the code:

   ```
   class testController extends Controller
   {
       public function updatePass(MiscValidation $request){
           //code here
       }
   }
   ```

Instead of using Request Class you use your own class which is an extension of the Request class.

Comment: sorry about step 9 can't make the code formatting work, any help is appreciated.

Comment: additional note: custom validation does not work if the field your trying to validate is empty.