# Form requests with custom rules

Tags: validation, request, laravel-5

I have a CustomFormRequest in which I want to use a custom rule. This is the rules() method in the FormRequest.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
            'name' => 'customrule'
    ];
}
```

The Validorclass

```
class CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator{
protected function customrule( $attribute, $value ) {
    return false;
}
```

I have a CustomServiceProvider with the following boot() method

```
public function boot()
{
   \Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
    {
         return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
    });
}
```

The CustomServiceProvider is listed in the app.php file.

Controller hat is using the formrequest

```
 public function store(CustomFormRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    dd("request succeeded");
```

This rule is not recognized by my FormRequest (or at least not executed), since the request always succeeds. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could make your own bind to register all new custom rules. I have described all the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417977/custom-validator-in-laravel-5/28425173#28425173

Comment: I changed my code to implement your solution, but it doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: If it does not work you need to show us the error

Comment: I return a hardcoded false in the function, but code in the controller that uses the FormRequest is still executing. This means that the function is not called right?

Comment: Show us the controller part that  where you call the validation class

Comment: I don't call validation anywhere, I am using the FormRequests.

Comment: Well, you need to call your custom form request like this:  `public function store(CustomFormRequest $request)` as parameter

Comment: I do that. Sorry if The naming is sometimes unclear

Comment: This seems that you are missing something small. Because the code should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you intend to make many custom rules? If not (I don't believe this scales well), here is what I use. Not that beautiful of a solution, but it's short and works:

Inside your request file add this:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;

class YourRequest extends Request {
...

  public function __construct(Factory $factory)
  {
      $factory->extendImplicit('customrule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
          //$value is what the user typed in the form or what came from POST
          // do some logic here, if the input is correct, return true else return false e.g.:

          if($value == 'what_is_expected')
             return true;
          else
             return false.

      },
          'Custom rule failed error message!'
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does the trick. 'someBooleanFunction' usus the function created in the CustomValidator (is this normal behaviour?). It seems a bit weird that is uses that function.

Comment: JorenV I didn't get what you said, what do you mean CustomValidator function? Is someBooleanFunction a real function? O.o

Comment: apparantly not, it seems I don't understand customvalidation enough.I can comment out the 'return booleanfunction', and it still works.

Comment: JorenV It doesn't exist. What do you intend to validate? Put your validation logic in there instead of the function. The `$value` parameter is what the user typed, so check if it is how it is supposed to be, if it is, return true, if not return false. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I mean that, if I write this: $factory->extendImplicit('customrule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {},       It uses the customrule function of my CustomValidator