# How to use a closure as a validator?

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to do something similar to the following in Laravel:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'sid' => function ($input) {
            // some custom validation logic.
        }
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'sid' => "Invalid SID!",
    ];
}
```

I want to do some simple single-use validation. Creating a custom validation is an overkill.

Comment: I use the `sometimes` rule for that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here, at least.

1. Create a custom rule via `AppServiceProvider` at `boot()` method:

   ```
    Validator::extend('my_rule', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        // some custom validation logic in order to return true or false
        return $value == 'my-valid-value';
    });
   ```

then, you apply the rule like:

```
    return [
        'sid' => ['my_rule'],
    ];
```

2. Or extending `ValidatorServiceProvider` class. Use this thread explained step by step: [Custom validator in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417977/custom-validator-in-laravel-5/28425173#28425173)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel 5.6 or later, you may use [closures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures).

To have $input available in the scope of the closure, you may use `use` keyword.

```
'sid' => [ function($attribute, $value, $fail) use $input {
   // your logic here
   //if that fails, so
    return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
 }
]
```