# Laravel Validating Arrays - pass 2 parameters?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I need to extend laravel validator creating a new validator but the problem is that I need to pass 2 parameters, one for `days` and one for `slots`. How to solve this?

Example `dd($request->all)` dump:

```
array:2 [
  "days" => array:2 [
    0 => "1" // Mon
    1 => "2" // Tue
  ]
  "slots" => array:2 [
    1 => array:2 [
      "open" => "09:00"
      "close" => "11:30"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      "open" => "16:00"
      "close" => "21:00"
    ]
  ]
]
```

It need to loop through `days` and check with `slots`.

Pseudo code, example:

```
foreach($days as $day) {
  foreach($slots as $slot) 
   {
      // Validation Logic for $day and $slot (open and close)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct method of making a custom Laravel Validation

Create your own **Validation Service Provider** using

```
php artisan make:provider ValidationServiceProvider
```

then go to `config\app.php` and add this to `providers`

```
App\Providers\ValidationServiceProvider::class
```

Now go to `ValidationServiceProvider.php` and add

```
use Validator;
```

to the top...

and this in the `boot()` function

```
Validator::extend('days_with_slots', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
  $slots = request()->get('slots');

  if(!is_array($slots)) return false;

  foreach($days as $day) {
    foreach($slots as $slot) {
      if(empty($slot[$day]) || empty($slot[$day]['open'] || empty($slot[$day]['close']))) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, use this in your rules

```
$rules['slots'] = 'days_with_slots'
```

You can also add a custom message for it, say

```
$message['days_with_slots'] = 'Open and Close Timings are required for the days selected'
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How can I define custom error message in `Validator::extend`? Each error message should have slots key

Comment: I want to put the value of open and close in the error message.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Sry for the late reply... Please tag me next time so I know... I wasn't notified for this for some reason. You can add all extended validations messages to either a global list... `resources/lang/validations.php` or make ur own Validator (by extending Illuminate\Validation\Validator) and overwrite the messages function with your own... and use your own Validator...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is another approach.

1. In your AppServiceProvider add your custom handler in `boot()` method:

   ```
   \Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
       return new MyCustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
   });
   ```
2. Create the resolver class:

   ```
   class MyCustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
   {
       public function validateSlotsInDays($attribute, $value, $parameters){
           $valid = false;
           $days = \Request::input($parametros[0]);
           $slots = $value;

           foreach($days as $day) {
               foreach($slots as $slot) {
                   // Validation Logic for $day and $slot (open and close)
               }
            }

           return $valid;
       }

       public function validateSlot($attribute, $value, $parameters){
           $valid = false;
           $days = \Request::input($parametros[0]);
           $slot = $value;
           foreach($days as $day) {
               // do whatever here
           }


           return $valid;
       }

   }
   ```
3. Finally, apply the rules. IF you need yo display an error if at least one slot is close, then you can use this rule:

   ```
   $rules = [
       'slots' => ['slots_in_days:days'],
   ];
   ```

   See how I am passing `days` as a parameter. In addition, if you need to validate each slot individually and display a message for each one of them, then apply the rule like this:

   ```
   $rules = [
       'slots.*' => ['slot:days'],
   ];
   ```

Addional docs:

- [Custom validator in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417977/custom-validator-in-laravel-5/28425173#28425173)
- [Form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: What is the difference between `Validator::resolver` and `Validator::extend` ?