# Controller Method not called with custom Form Request Method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

For form validation I made a `Request class` via `php artisan make:request UpdatePlanRequest`.

However after using the `UpdatePlanRequest` class in store the method isn't called anymore.

The `UpdatePlanRequest`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdatePlanRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {   //TODO: CHECK IF THE PROTOTYPE IDS ARE OWNED BY THE USER (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662579/validate-an-array-of-integers/42693970)
        return [
            'start_date' => 'required|date',
            'end_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date',
            'name' => 'required|string'
        ];
    }
}
```

The controller method:

```php
use App\Http\Requests\UpdatePlanRequest;

public function store(UpdatePlanRequest $request)
    {
        //
        dd('hello');
    }
```

If the function header is `store(Request $request)` `hello` is shown, in that example it isn't.

The custom Request class is necessary to call `$request->validated();` later for validation purposes according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests).

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your routes, as well as the create form?

Comment: Show us the form itself.

Comment: It was an issue with naming. I did some refactoring wrong and there were different terms for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have your Request class as being abstract? The default class that is created when running `php artisan make:request <name>` doesn't define the class as being abstract. This seems to work for me, but not when declaring it as abstract.

Answer (score 0):

`$request->validated();` is used to retrieve the validated inputs, so just by calling the `UpdatePlanRequest` it should validate the request

Comment: The store method isn't even called. I get redirected to the /create page.

Comment: @LewisTudor you get redirected because of validation; that should happen

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Try This 
    use App\Http\Requests\UpdatePlanRequest;

    public function store(UpdatePlanRequest $request)
        {
           $validatedData = $request->validated();
           dd('$validatedData');
           $profile = new Profile([
            'user_id'              => $request->get('user_id'),

        ]);
        $profile->save();
        echo $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Profile details Succefully Added!');
        return redirect('create')->with('success', 'Data saved!');

        }

Your route will be.

Route::get('profile','ProfileController@store');
Route::post('profile/create','ProfileController@store')->name('create');
```

Comment: The store method isn't even called. I get redirected to the /create page.

Comment: Check validation errors on create page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: Thank you!
Validation error checking got me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Well this works right!
When the method is called, it checks the request class (UpdatePlanRequest). If there is an error, it does not enter the method anymore and you can not see the output of dd() function.
If the data is correct after checking the rules, then dd() will be displayed.
You must manage errors

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue when I needed to return error message from Laravel `FormRequest`. The main reason is that the `failedValidation()` method in the `FormRequest` file will by default redirect when the data you send is invalid. Therefore, we can simply solve the above problem by customizing the `failedValidation()` method.

Please open the `FormRequest.php` file and you will see that the `failedValidation()` method takes a parameter which is a validator. We also see that `FormRequest` provides us with a `getValidatorInstance()` method. Here is the code I customized in the `BaseRequest.php` file. From now on, requests that need to return error messages will inherit from `BaseRequest` instead of `FormRequest`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

class BaseRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $stopOnFirstFailure = false;

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        return $validator->errors()->messages();
    }

    public function getValidator()
    {
        return $this->getValidatorInstance();
    }
}
```

FormRequest custom file

```php
...

class StoreRequest extends BaseRequest
{
    \\ ...

    public function rule()
    {
        return [];
    }
    
    public function message()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

And in controller file we have

```php
<?php

namespace Modules\User\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    \\ ...

    public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        $errors = $request->failedValidation($request->getValidator());
        if ($errors) return response()->json(['errors' => $errors], 422);
        return $this->service->createUser($data);
    }
}
```

Good luck!