# laravel array validation - work out depth for array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to validate recursive data which could have any number of levels e.g.

```
[
    'name' => 'test',
    'children' => [
        [
            'name' => 'test2'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'test3',
            'children' => [
                'name' => 'test4'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'test5',
            'children' => [
                'name' => 'test6'
                'children' => [
                    'name' => 'test7'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

In this example I would require the following rules to ensure that a name is specified at each level:

```
$rules = [
    'name' => ['required'],
    'children' => ['array'],
    'children.*.name' => ['required'],
    'children.*.children' => ['array'],
    'children.*.children.*.name' => ['required'],
    'children.*.children.*.children' => ['array'],
    'children.*.children.*.children.*.name' => ['required'],
]
```

How could I dynamically generate the validation rules based on the data coming in?

Comment: I have no idea if it's natively possible. However, What I would do is to make a [custom validator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28425173/8068675) that will recursively test each nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function save(array $attributes)
 {
    $errors = tap(new MessageBag(), fn($messageBag) => $this->validate($attributes, $messageBag));
    if ($errors->isNotEmpty()) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages($errors->toArray());
    }
 }


/**
 * @param array       $attributes
 * @param IMessageBag $messageBag
 * @param string      $prefix
 * @return void
 */
protected function validate(array $attributes, IMessageBag $messageBag, string $prefix = ''): void
{
    $validator = Validator::make($attributes, [
        'ref'            => 'required',
        'parent_ref'     => 'nullable',
        'name'           => 'required',
        'original_name'  => 'required',
        'children'       => 'nullable|array',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        foreach ($validator->errors()->toArray() as $fieldName => $errors) {
            $messageBag->merge(["{$prefix}{$fieldName}" => $errors]);
        }
    }

    $children = $attributes['children'] ?? [];
    if (!empty($children)) {
        foreach ($children as $key => $child) {
            $this->validate($child, $messageBag, "{$prefix}children.{$key}.");
        }
    }
}
```