# Laravel validation custom messages not showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I am trying to validate my `start_date` and `end_date`.   `start_date` works perfectly and `end_date` works but the error message doesn't show.

If i put the `end_date` before the second date the validator works but the error message doesn't show.

My validator in the controller

```
'start_date' => [ Rule::unique('reservations')->where(function($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('pitch_id', 'LIKE','%'.$request->pitch_id.'%');
})],
    'end_date'=> ['required','date','after:start_date'],
]);
```

My view

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control " name="end_date"  id="end_date" required>
    @error('end_date')
    <span class="invalid-feedback " role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

My custom messages:

```
'custom' => [
    'start_date' => [
        'unique' => 'date deja reservé changer du date ou changer le terrain',
    ],
    'end_date' => [
        'after' => 'la date de fin doit etre apres la date du debut',
    ],
],
```

The messages  of the `start_date` works but the `end_date` doesn't.

Comment: i think here you can find a lot of answers that may do the job https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817045/laravel-4-validate-start-and-end-date-with-before-and-after-validation

Comment: Your question is tagged with both Laravel 4 and 5 - which are you using?